# Removing apache@localhost from my email header?

Tags: email, apache

I hope someone might have an idea on this.  I'm running a Magento website on an Amazon Linux server (basically CentOS) with an Apache webserver.  I also use Google Apps for managing mydomain.com's mail.

I was able to successfully set up the MX, SPF and DKIM records for the server and got them working, so that I receive a "Pass" for both SPF and DKIM when I send emails.  However, I've run into a strange problem I can't seem to get past --- part of the headers for the emails I send always says:

```
Received: (from apache@localhost) by mydomain.com
```

I've searched high and low for a way to change this to use "mail@mydomain.com" instead, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Among things I've tried:

- Changing the php.ini to say: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mail@mydomain.com
- Adding to mydomain.conf's virtualhost the line: ServerAdmin mail@mydomain.com
- Setting the Return-Path to "Yes" in the Magento backend (System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings.

I'm not sure if there's anything else that might be affecting the mail sends.  If anyone has an idea it would be much appreciated, thank you!

**Edit**: The contents of my /etc/hosts file are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   www.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
```

**Edit 2**:  I thought it might help if I added the headers of the email, in case that might give some clues to what might be going on (I've changed a lot of values to keep it generalized).

```
Delivered-To: zerowing@email.com
Received: by 123.123.123.123 with SMTP id abcdefg123456790;
        Fri, 3 Apr 2015 08:35:04 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 456.456.456.456 with SMTP id asdfqwerhjkl234hjkl.789.78909876789;
        Fri, 03 Apr 2015 08:35:03 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <mail@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com (ec2-11-11-111-11.amazonaws.com. [66.66.777.77])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id asdkfjhkjdfha839383.105.2015.04.03.08.35.02
        for <zerowing@email.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 03 Apr 2015 08:35:03 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of mail@mydomain.com designates 66.66.777.77 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.66.777.77;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of mail@mydomain.com designates 66.66.777.77 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mail@mydomain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (www.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1])
    by mydomain.com (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id t33FZ29p004251
    for <zerowing@email.com>; Fri, 3 Apr 2015 15:35:02 GMT
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com;
    s=default; t=fjIFDJF9049;
    bh=fjO4J4f09j409JF04J909f4j904JF940F9/Y=;
    h=To:Subject:From:Date;
    b=F4J90FJ490j09j490FJ094J0j94f90j409j490Jf90j904JF09j490fj904jf094J
     f09J40F9J904fj049J099j49J049J0FJijffjdlfjldkDLFJKLdjflEJFOIJFOEIEO
     JF9JF049j409j0F094J09FJ049jf049j=
Received: (from apache@localhost) <----------- THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO CHANGE
    by mydomain.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id fkdjfljlfsra39393;
    Fri, 3 Apr 2015 15:35:01 GMT
Message-Id: <201504031535.fkdjfljlfsra39393@mydomain.com>
To: =?utf-8?B?Sm9lIEdhcmNpYQ==?= <zerowing@email.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?VGVzdCBOZXdzbGV0dGVyLCBwbGVhc2UgaWdub3Jl?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 48:Sendmail.php
From: "mydomain.com" <mail@mydomain.com>
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2015 15:35:01 +0000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: you need to go to: System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System ->Set Return-Path -> Yes or w/e email address you want it to be. Just found it today. It's ridiculous that this is not a default setting for Magento.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Apps, I'd recommend installing [SMTP Pro](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension). It'll allow you to configure it so that email is sent from Google Apps, and not directly from your server. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your etc/hosts says the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mydomain.com
```

Change it to

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com localhost
```

Comment: I decided to give this a try just now, but unfortunately the result was still the same.  My file actually had a few lines of settings inside already, I'll add the contents back into my question.